# How to update the element value inside serialized dynamic JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json-deserialization

I have a requirement in .net(C#) where I need to send the dynamic type of object inside the JSON and need to update it another API and send it again to another API for processing.
I am having difficulty de-serializing it to dynamic type to update the one of the property.

I am able to get the values with "RootElement.GetProperty()" but could not fins anything for setting the values inside the JSON.

Appreciate the help.

Example of JSON structure which is getting passed to .net core api:

```
 {
  "TaskId": "24332",
  "Code": "Sample_code",
      "Type": 1,
      "Name": "New Product",
      "Params": {
        "Year": "2020",
    "Filter": "LTH"
    }
}
```

Comment: Any example of json would be easy to help you out.

Comment: @Sreenath: added example in question

Comment: Still not clear what is being asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use Newtonsoft's native objects JObject, JArray or JToken.

For example, in your case, if you want to modify the Params property, you only have to access the object and add/edit the property:

```
string json = @"{'TaskId':'24332','Code':'Sample_code','Type':1,'Name':'New Product','Params':{'Year':'2020','Filter':'LTH'}}";

JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

if (jObject["Params"] is JObject p) {
    p.Add("ProductType", "Battery");
}

string newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using `ExpandoObject`

You can try using the `ExpandoObject`. This way, you can add/edit properties on the expanding object and then serialize again and have the extended json object.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonText, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netcore-3.1

> Represents an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time.

### Using `Json.Text`

Guessing that's your approach. Check [How to add property in existing json using System.Text.Json library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302522/how-to-add-property-in-existing-json-using-system-text-json-library) for solutions.