# Taking a JSON array with file paths to update the JSON array for date last modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have an API which I use dapper to connect to a SQL database to find the file path for documents related to a certain ID. The result is returned in JSON format as follows:

```
[{"DOC-ID": 1, "DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH": "/PATH/FILENAME.DOC"},{"DOC-ID": 2, "DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH": "/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC"}]
```

I am trying to get my API to deserialize the JSON data then link that too a model (I prefer to not use models but the only solution I found was using JSON DOM which is briefly discussed on MS website but does not provide an example of how to loop through the JSON array so I could not move forward with this example). When I try to deserialize the dapper query result I get the error indicated below (shown at the line item in the code). I am not sure what is triggering this as I would think the QuerySingle could be deserialized with this method. Once this error is fixed I need to check the files last modified date and save that value to the model which I then again need to serialize to send to the front end! I have spent so much time on this so some help would be much appreciated!

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MainReviewDocuments([FromForm] string ID)
{
    //Using FormData on frontend
    //checking ID exists on searching in dashboard
    if (ID == null || ID.Length == 0)
    {
        return Ok(new { Result = "Failed" });
    }
    else
    {
        //We have parameters here just in case we want to use them
        var UserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;

        String query = "select dbo.A2Q_0132W_RR_IDDocumentation_JSON(@ID) as output";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var json = connection.QuerySingle<string>(query, new { ID = ID}); 

            MainReviewDocuments? mainreviewdocuments = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MainReviewDocuments>(json); // this line draws an error 'The JSON value could not be converted to Project.Models.MainReviewDocuments. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.'
            var rootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).ToString(), "Files");

            foreach (var document in mainreviewdocuments)
            {
                filePath = Path.Combine(rootPath, document.DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH);
                //Check file system for each file path and set last modified value to model object LAST_MODIFIED. Struggling with this as well
            }
            return Ok(mainreviewdocuments); // Can I use Ok() method to convert model back to JSON?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original call, you need to de-serialize to a `List`:

```
MainReviewDocuments? mainreviewdocuments = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MainReviewDocuments>>(json);
```

and then access your properties are required.

Using `Newtonsoft.Json` library:

You can de-serialize your `JSON` string that you receive from your `DB` into the following class:

```
public class MainReviewDocuments
{
    [JsonProperty("DOC-ID")]
    public int DOCID { get; set; }
    public string DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use `dynamic` to de-serialize your `JSON`:

```
var mainreviewdocuments = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

and then access the properties as shown in the example below.

You can refer to a working [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sCUaMk) below:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myJsonString=@"[{'DOC-ID': 1, 'DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH': '/PATH/FILENAME.DOC'},{'DOC-ID': 2, 'DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH': '/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC'}]";
        var mainreviewdocuments =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MainReviewDocuments>>(myJsonString);
        Console.WriteLine("Example using Model: \n");
        foreach(var item in mainreviewdocuments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.DOCID);
            Console.WriteLine(item.DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH);         
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Example using Dynamic: \n");
        
        //Example using dynamic
        var mainreviewdocumentsDynamic=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(myJsonString);
        foreach(var item in mainreviewdocumentsDynamic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item["DOC-ID"]);
            Console.WriteLine(item["DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH"]);      
        }
    }
}

public class MainReviewDocuments
{
    [JsonProperty("DOC-ID")]
    public int DOCID { get; set; }
    public string DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Example using Model: 

1
/PATH/FILENAME.DOC
2
/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC


Example using Dynamic: 

1
/PATH/FILENAME.DOC
2
/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC
```

Using `System.Text.Json` library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
       var myJsonString="[{\"DOC-ID\": 1, \"DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH\": \"/PATH/FILENAME.DOC\"},{\"DOC-ID\": 2, \"DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH\": \"/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC\"}]";
       var mainreviewdocuments = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MainReviewDocuments>>(myJsonString);
        Console.WriteLine("Example using Model: \n");
        foreach(var item in mainreviewdocuments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.DOCID);
            Console.WriteLine(item.DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH);         
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Example using Dynamic: \n");
        using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(myJsonString))
        {
           foreach (JsonElement element in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
           {
               Console.WriteLine(element.GetProperty("DOC-ID"));
               Console.WriteLine(element.GetProperty("DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH"));
            }
        }
    }
}


public class MainReviewDocuments
{
    [JsonPropertyName("DOC-ID")]
    public int DOCID { get; set; }
    public string DOCUMENT_FULL_PATH { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
Example using Model: 

1
/PATH/FILENAME.DOC
2
/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC


Example using Dynamic: 

1
/PATH/FILENAME.DOC
2
/PATH/FILENAME2.DOC
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nEjPIK

You can read more on the comparison between the two libraries in this [article](https://inspiration.nlogic.ca/en/a-comparison-of-newtonsoft.json-and-system.text.json)

Comment: Thank you for this! I am actually still drawing an error for both methods. I know my query returns a JSON string but using the class method and using List<MainReviewDocuments> it will not compile due to cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.MainReviewDocuments>' to 'Project.Models.MainReviewDocuments' . Using the <dynamic> method it indicates Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable''. My JSON array when returned does not have a @. That ok?

Comment: I also do not use JsonConvert which I hope is okay. I use JsonSerializer which is a default MS library. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 Can you please post your `MainReviewDocuments` model class please? Have you tried using `Newtonsoft` package for parsing your `JSON`? You can parse with dynamic using the default MS library: `var mainreviewdocuments = JsonNode.Parse(json);`

Comment: I have used newtonsoft and your code does work. I was just trying to stick with MS libraries rather than third party but I cannot for the life of me make it work ha. My model is very similar to what you put but the code I did above is just a dumbed down version due to confidentiality. Does your example work using MS serializer()?.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 I have updated my answer to include `System.Text` library also for your scenario. Hope it helps you out.

Comment: Just curious can system.text.json also use dynamic similar to JsonConvert? And any reason to use JsonConvert over system.text.json?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 I have updated my answer to include the above `dynamic` scenario and also a link to an article outlining the differences between the two libraries. If my answer helped you out, you can accept it and up-vote. Thanks

Comment: There is also one last thing. There is a property I am adding to the deserialized JSON array called LAST_MODIFIED which is basically the files on the servers last modified date. I know how to get the value but I do not know how to add it to the JsonElement for dynamic. I see you can use element.GetProperty() to get the value but how can I add property and set a property value as I loop through each element? Not seeing a method for that.  For JSONConvert it was easy but I am trying to use the system.text.json example you created as the article you reference kind of points towards using it.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 Okay, so you have a property that is not a part of your `JSON` and you want to access that property while accessing your elements of your `JSON` string? How are you doing that? Can you give an example?

Comment: Using your code in the foreach loop I need to add a property "LAST_MODIFIED" and set its value equal to something, say a string called "testvalue". Is there a method to do this?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 You can refer to this question for your purpose if I am understanding your query correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302522/how-to-add-property-in-existing-json-using-system-text-json-library